# Flutter will not build on iOS with Firebase

Tags: flutter

I am not a very experienced developer.  I have run against the following error and can't figure out how to get around it.

Steps already taken:

1. Wipe iOS folder and replace with iOS folder from new project.
2. Insert `GoogleService-Info.plist` file to runner/runner using XCode
3. pod install from the command line
4. pod update from the command line
5. flutter clean
6. flutter run -v from the command line

This is the output portion with error:

```
Error output from Xcode build:
           ↳
[   +1 ms]     ** BUILD FAILED **


               The following build commands failed:
                CompileC

/Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_core
                .build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebaseCorePlugin.o
                /Users/shannongalway/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+9/ios/Classes/FirebaseCorePlugin.m normal x86_64 objective-c
                com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
               (1 failure)

[   +1 ms] Xcode's output:
           ↳
[  +74 ms]     Build settings from command line:
                   ARCHS = x86_64
                   BUILD_DIR = /Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios
                   COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE = NO
                   FLUTTER_SUPPRESS_ANALYTICS = true
                   SCRIPT_OUTPUT_STREAM_FILE = /var/folders/bv/50ls2w0n1tl136bfb5xpp_hw0000gn/T/flutter_build_log_pipe.lhBeoU/pipe_to_stdout
                   SDKROOT = iphonesimulator13.1
                   VERBOSE_SCRIPT_LOGGING = YES

               note: Using new build system
               note: Planning build
               note: Constructing build description
               WriteAuxiliaryFile

                     ProcessInfoPlistFile
                     /Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.framework/Info.plist
                     /Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics-Info.plist (in target
                     'firebase_analytics' from project 'Pods')
                         cd /Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/ios/Pods
                         builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\
                         Files/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics-Info.plist -producttype com.apple.product-type.framework -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform
                         iphonesimulator -o
                         /Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.framework/Info.plist

                     CompileC
                     /Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulat
                     or/firebase_analytics.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.o
                     /Users/shannongalway/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-5.0.2/ios/Classes/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m normal
                     x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'firebase_analytics' from project 'Pods')
                         cd /Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/ios/Pods
                         export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
                         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target x86_64-apple-ios8.0-simulator
                         -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu11 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-weak -fmodules -gmodules
                         -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval=86400
                         -fmodules-prune-after=345600
                         -fbuild-session-file=/Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation
                         -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module
                         -fmodule-name=firebase_analytics -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes
                         -Werror=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars
                         -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch
                         -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized
                         -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion
                         -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof
                         -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG=1 -DDEBUG=1 -DCOCOAPODS=1
                         -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot
                         /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.1.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing
                         -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes
                         -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote
                         /Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesim
                         ulator/firebase_analytics.build/firebase_analytics-generated-files.hmap
                         -I/Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphones
                         imulator/firebase_analytics.build/firebase_analytics-own-target-headers.hmap
                         -I/Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphones
                         imulator/firebase_analytics.build/firebase_analytics-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay
                         /Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesim
                         ulator/firebase_analytics.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote
                         /Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesim
                         ulator/firebase_analytics.build/firebase_analytics-project-headers.hmap
                         -I/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_analytics/include
                         -I/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/ios/Pods/Headers/Public
                         -I/Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphones
                         imulator/firebase_analytics.build/DerivedSources-normal/x86_64
                         -I/Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphones
                         imulator/firebase_analytics.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
                         -I/Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphones
                         imulator/firebase_analytics.build/DerivedSources
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_analytics
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/BoringSSL-GRPC
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseFirestore
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstanceID
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransport
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-C++
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-Core
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/leveldb-library
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/ios/.symlinks/flutter/ios
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks
                         -F/Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -include
                         /Users/shannongalway/IdeaProjects/carlinehound/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics-prefix.pch -MMD -MT
                         dependencies -MF
                         /Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesim
                         ulator/firebase_analytics.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.d --serialize-diagnostics
                         /Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesim
                         ulator/firebase_analytics.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.dia -c
                         /Users/shannongalway/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-5.0.2/ios/Classes/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m -o
                         /Users/shannongalway/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gujmunagyejhsgfssbevzrusvdkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesim
                         ulator/firebase_analytics.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.o
```

flutter doctor

```
Shannons-Mac:carlinehound shannongalway$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.9.1+hotfix.6, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G1012, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6 at /Users/shannongalway/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 68587a0916 (8 weeks ago), 2019-09-13 19:46:58 -0700
    • Engine revision b863200c37
    • Dart version 2.5.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/shannongalway/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.1, Build version 11A1027
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2.3)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 40.2.4
    • Dart plugin version 192.7402

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro • C7EAA15B-AD74-4525-B314-3A19D59A9DA4 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-1 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

From pubspec.yaml

```
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+6
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
```

I feel like I have searched just about as hard as I can for a solution, but I am simply walking in circles.

Comment: I experienced iOS build failure with Firebase on the stable channel. Try `flutter channel master && flutter upgrade` and try again.

Comment: I've tried stable, master, and dev channels.  All have the same error unfortunately.

Comment: hmm, maybe take a look at my `pubspec.yaml` see if anything is different? https://github.com/tianhaoz95/iwfp/blob/master/iwfpapp/pubspec.yaml. mine builds fine so far: https://github.com/tianhaoz95/iwfp/runs/290454767

Comment: my guess so far is an outdated firebase package as they are actively being developed, and at the same time, iOS 13 breaks things.

Comment: I am now only getting the following error when I try to run the app on simulator:

'Firebase.h:45:13: fatal error: could not build module 'FirebaseFirestore'
        #import <FirebaseFirestore/FirebaseFirestore.h>'

Comment: I setup an entirely new project and only added the firestore and firebase core dependencies.  I also added the 'GoogleService-Info.plist' file through Xcode.  The build fails in the exact same manner.

Comment: hmmm... that's weird. Have you tried build it in xcode?

Comment: In the new project I have narrowed it down to the cloud_firestore dependency.  When I comment it out, the problem goes away.  Leave it in and:
error:
`FIRFirestoreSettings.h:46:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type`

Building in Xcode has same outcome.

Comment: oh, I see. It seems to be a base language objective c vs. swift issue. I remember seeing this long-discussed issue. Maybe check out https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26574

Comment: Yeah, I ran across that thread as well.  I am already using swift.  I will however give this a try in VSCode instead of Intellij.

Comment: Just tried with a fresh project in VScode and same result.  Taking it step by step, everything works until I include the cloud_firestore dependency.  I have an inquiry on the Github issue tracker.

Answer (score 3):

Things to check for:

1. Did you download `GoogleService-Info.plist`?
2. Adding the file `GoogleService-Info.plist` should be done through xcode  by going to Runner > right click the Runner folder > Add Files to "Runner"

[image]

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear in my opening post, but this was item two on the list.  It was added to Xcode using the method you show above.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can find is to actually remove the "strong" attribute in the referenced line of the file.

`FIRFirestoreSettings.h:46:1: error: property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type`

Once this is done the project runs and builds without problems.  This method is obviously not a fix, but a pretty hokey workaround.  This will comeback.

Comment: How did you figure out that workaround? I'm having a similar build issue with Firebase.

Comment: Honestly I don't remember the source.  I struggled with this for two days and at some point came across a post which suggest this method.  I resisted because I knew it wasn't a fix but rather a band aid.  To get the project rolling again I just did it.